# Loop through array to assign dynamic variable with results from 'find'

Tags: bash, loops, shell, find

I'm trying to assign the results of `find` to a dynamic variable using the entries of an array both as the variable name and search string.

```
databases=(ABC DEF GHI JKL)
for i in "${databases[@]}"
do
    schema_$i=$(find '/hana/shared/backup_service/backup_shr/Schema' -type d -iname ${i} -mtime 0)
done
```

The result should be 0 to 4 variables that look something like this (depending on how many folders were found):

```
schema_ABC=/hana/shared/backup_service/backup_shr/Schema/ABC
```

However when I try this I get 'No such file or directory' as an error.

```
./find_schema.sh: line 4: schema_ABC=/hana/shared/backup_service/backup_shr/Schema/ABC: No such file or directory
./find_schema.sh: line 4: schema_DEF=/hana/shared/backup_service/backup_shr/Schema/DEF: No such file or directory
./find_schema.sh: line 4: schema_GHI=: command not found
./find_schema.sh: line 4: schema_JKL=/hana/shared/backup_service/backup_shr/Schema/JKL: No such file or directory
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
Server:/hana/shared/backup_service/backup_shr/Schema # ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Sep 29  2020 Test
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 24 21:15 ABC
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 24 21:30 DEF
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 12 22:00 GHI
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 24 21:45 JKL
```

I believe that I'm not declaring that variable correctly but I can't make out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
schema_$i=$(cmd)
```

When bash parses that line, it first checks for variable assignments.  Since `$` is not a valid character in a variable name, it does not see any variable assignments.  Then it expands the string `schema_$i` to the string `schema_ABC` (or whatever the current value of `$i` is).  Then it executes `cmd` to get some output, and then it attempts to execute the command `schema_ABC=foo`, but fails to find a command that matches that name.  Intuitively, you are trying to make `bash` evaluate the string `schema_ABC=foo`, in which case you would need to tell it to do so explicitly with `eval "schema_$i=$(find ...)"`.  But you really don't want to go down that rabbit hole.

Instead, you could use an associative array and do something like:

```
declare -A schema
databases=(ABC DEF GHI JKL)
for i in "${databases[@]}"
do
    schema[$i]=$(...) 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to declare dynamic variable names is to use `declare`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

databases=(ABC DEF GHI JKL)
for i in "${databases[@]}"
do
    declare "schema_$i"="$(find '/hana/shared/backup_service/backup_shr/Schema' -type d -iname "$i" -mtime 0)"
done
```

**remark:** The find command doesn't seem right; it will only list directories whose name is "$i"